# How to include a not-yet indexed parameter into if-else

Tags: r

I have the following function:

```
foo <- function(...){
  dots <- list(...) 
  response <- dots[[1]]
  
  if(is(dots[[2]],'list') == TRUE){print('yes')} else print('no')
}
```

This produces the following output:

> foo('yes'):
> Error in dots[[2]] : subscript out of bounds

How can I use a 'not-yet' indexed parameter so that I can stall the function when it's `TRUE` or when its `FALSE`. For example, when it's `TRUE` I would do some stuff based on this, otherwise when it is `FALSE` the part of the function that uses it won't run.

However, R want's me to at-least index `dots` with some list values.

For example, If I wanted to use just:

```
foo('yes')
>Error in dots[[2]] : subscript out of bounds

#otherwise
foo('yes',c('some','list'))
>'yes'
```

I want to be able to run `foo('yes')` and for it to print `no`. Essentially, some parameters won't get used in the function, and so in this case when it's not assigned anything then run the `else` statement.

Picking up on @Rui Barradas and @Allan Camerons comments, I can achieve the same expectation with `function(pred=NULL,...)` by using:

```
foo <- function(...){
  dots <- list(...) 
  
  response <- dots[[1]]
  print(response)
  
  if(length(dots) > 1){
    if(is(dots[[2]],'list') == TRUE){
      print('yes')
      } else print('no')
  } else if (length(dots) == 1){
  dots[[2]] = NULL
    }
       }
```

Results:

```
> foo('yes',list(1, 2, 3))
[1] "yes"

> foo('yes')
[1] "yes"
```

Are there any cleaner alternatives to this that reduce the amount of code? My approach produces quite some clutter. The only issue I have with this is that If I wanted `dots[[3]]`, I would have to implement further conditionals to access this or set it to `NULL`.

Comment: I am not sure but are you looking for `length(dots)`? This will give you the last valid index number.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I have multiple parameter values so ```dots[[5]], dots[[7]] ...```, some of these only take `characters, numerics, or  lists`, and ```dots[[2]]``` takes a list. However, it's only conditional that ```dots[[2]]]``` may take any values. So when It does take a list of values I want it to `print('yes')`, otherwise when it is assigned nothing `print('no')`, but when it's assigned nothing it throws an error instead.

Comment: But you can't assign _nothing_ to dots[[2]] (unless you specifically set it to NULL. If you have ordered parameters that are supposed to have set types, why are you using dots rather than naming them?

Comment: @AllanCameron ah I see I tried `function(pred = NULL, ...)` and this works when I replace `dots[[2]]` with `pred`. Would there be a way to replicate this with dots by assigning `NULL` to it? I am specifically using `dots` to reduce naming all the parameters.

Comment: @AllanCameron I have updated the post, seems like I answered my own question with my previous comment.

Comment: @RuiBarradas thank you for the hint, I have used this alongside with Allans comment and achieved what I was after.

Comment: Then please post as an answer so others can learn. Comments are ephemeral.